# How do I search for a string with quotes?

Tags: c#

I am searching for the string

```
<!--m--><li class="g w0"><h3 class=r><a href="
```

within the HTML source of this link:

http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Santarus+Inc‎

This is how I am searching for it:

```
string html_string = "http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=" + biocompany;
html = new WebClient().DownloadString(html_string);

d=html.IndexOf(@"<!--m--><li class=""g w0""><h3 class=r><a href=""",1);
```

For some reason it is finding an occurrence of it at position 45 (in other words d=45) but this is incorrect.

Here are the first couple hundred characters of the string HTML:

```
<!doctype html><head><title>Santarus Inc&#8206; - Google Search</title><script>window.google={kEI:\"b6jES5nPD4rysQOokrGDDQ\",kEXPI:\"23729,24229,24249,24260,24414,24457\",kCSI:{e:\"23729,24229,24249,24260,24414,24457\",ei:\"b6jES5nPD4rysQOokrGDDQ\",expi:\"23729,24229,24249,24260,24414,24457\"},ml:function(){},kHL:\"en\",time:function(){return(new Date).getTime()},log:function(b,d,c){var a=new Image,e=google,g=e.lc,f=e.li;a.onerror=(a.onload=(a.onabort=function(){delete g[f]}));g[f]=a;c=c||\"/gen_204?atyp=i&ct=\"+b+\"&cad=\"+d+\"&zx=\"+google.time();a.src=c;e.li=f+1},lc:[],li:0,Toolbelt:{}};\nwindow.google.sn=\"web\";window.google.timers={load:{t:{start:(new Date).getTime()}}};try{}catch(u){}window.google.jsrt_kill=1;\n</script><style>body{background:#fff;color:#000;margin:3px 8px}#gbar,#guser{font-size:13px;padding-top:1px !important}#gbar{float:left;height:22px}#guser{padding-bottom:7px !important;text-align:right}.gbh,.gbd{border-top:1px solid #c9d7f1;font-size:1px}.gbh
```

Comment: Are you trying to pull the url and link text from the link?  If so, it might be better to use RegEx so you don't have to find the index of two different strings, then substring between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post more code. My guess is your html variable isn't storing what you think it is. Are you reading the html line by line, by chance? And are you appending or replacing the prior contents? At any rate, put a breakpoint immediately before or after the .IndexOf call and check the contents of html.

**Edit** I ran through a sample of your code and am not finding your string.

```
string biocompany = "Santarus Inc‎";
string html_string = "http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=" + biocompany;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string html = client.DownloadString(html_string);
    int d = html.IndexOf(@"<!--m--><li class=""g w0""><h3 class=r>");
    Console.WriteLine(d);
}
```

I am not sure what you are doing based on the code you posted.

Comment: anthony i just posted some more

Comment: Step through the section of code. Verify that the code is performing exactly as you intend and the variables hold what you mean for them to hold. I ran your hypothetical scenario and found that the html variable did not contain the value you were searching for (in other words, IndexOf returned -1).

Comment: anthony thank you for your response, i did verify and i am finding <!--m--><li class="g w0"><h3 class=r><a href=", as intended, but programmatically its returning 45 in all scenarios

Comment: anthony, thanks for the update, i really appreciate the help. if you go to google and search for anything, view the source code, you will find the string i am searching for

Comment: See my edit. I am not sure what you are doing, I cannot reproduce your results. My ninja phantom debugging skills aren't all that great, but I can only guess you've got something wrong beyond what you are describing.

Answer (score 3):

You are not searching for the string you say you are.

If you are searching for this:

```
<!--m--><li class="g w0"><h3 class=r>
```

Use this:

```
@"<!--m--><li class=""g w0""><h3 class=r>"
```

Not:

```
@"<!--m--><li class=""g w0""><h3 class=r><a href="""
```

**Update:** (following comments)

I ran a google search following the URL you have used. I found no case of an `<li>` tag with a quoted `class` attribute. Are you looking for the correct string?

Comment: No it isn't. As example f in your link shows, quotes in a verbatim string literal are escaped as `""`. Regular string literals use `\"`, like example e.

Comment: i revised it please look again

Comment: oded: i dont understand how that can be. im opening that URL in both mozilla and firefox and i am indeed finding that string

Answer (score 0):

[Anthony has given correct solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631731/how-do-i-search-for-a-string-with-quotes/2631841#2631841)

But it is also true that the browsers are showing the download html different as compared to downloaded in the code.

That's why the index returned is coming to be -1, and not even 45, as mentioned by "every_answer_gets_a_point" :)

This is another question in itself - why is it happening so.

As far as the searching is concerned, Anthony has given the answer already.